# Use of uninitialized value $site in string

Tags: perl

'm trying to execute this code but it's already give me the following error :
**Use of uninitialized value $site in string at C:\Users\USER\Desktop\script.pl line 35.**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use LWP::UserAgent;
use File::Slurp;
use warnings;
use strict;
use HTTP::Request;

open (THETARGET, "<list.txt") || die "[-] Can't open the file";
my @TARGETS = <THETARGET>;
close THETARGET;
my $link=$#TARGETS + 1;

OUTER: foreach my $site(@TARGETS){
    chomp($site);
}

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->timeout(10);
my $url = my $site;
my $picture = "teest.png";
my %args;
my $field_name = "file[]";
my $buf ;
my $buf_ref = $args{'buf'} || \$buf ;


my $value = read_file( $picture , binmode => ':raw' , scalar_ref => 1 );

my $response = $ua->post( $url,
            Content_Type => 'form-data',
            Content => [ $field_name => ["$picture"] ]
            );
print "$site";
```

Comment: The code you posted doesn't have 35 lines. Please provide the code that actually provided the error.

Comment: `my $site` creates a new scalar initialized to `undef`. You assign this scalar to `$url`, setting it to `undef` as well. You then use `$url` as if it contains a url, but it doesn't.

Comment: You are re-declaring `$site` with the foreach. The for loop only does a chomp of `$site` and that is it. `%args` is declared, but not use, `$buf` `$buf_ref` etc. A lot wrong with this code.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you are expecting is the value of $site to carry over from the for loop, but because it is defined *in* the for loop, its scope is limited to that loop.  Perhaps what you intended is for all of the following code to also be inside that loop.  Otherwise, that value for $site ceases to exist at the closing-brace two lines after it was created.  Your line

```
my $url = my $site;
```

then creates a *new* variable $site (which is undef), and that undef value is used to set $url, so it is also undef.  I suspect you initially had

```
my $url = $site;
```

then added the extra "my" to resolve an earlier error.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Your explanation of the problem is good, but your proposed solution doesn't work. Did you try it? And why do you think the loop only iterates once?

Comment: You are right, @melpomene... I misread the original code and thought only one value was being read in for TARGET.  I've corrected my response now